# Mixing Parameterized Query and Sub-query on Insert

Tags: java, sql, sybase

I have a colleague who wants to attempt the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
VALUES (?, (SELECT Id FROM ColumnD WHERE x=y), ?)
```

Sybase complains about this as it does not seem to allow subqueries in the VALUES portion of the query.  Does anyone know of a way around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
INSERT INTO table (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
SELECT
  ?,
  Id,
  ?
FROM
  TableD
WHERE
  x = y
```

(Or similar)